# .htaccess too many redirect after a END flag and Require all denied command

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to secure a sensible wordpress install, I need to make wp-login.php unreachable but last WordPress rewrite rule always being called even if a blocking rule it's on top of the .htaccess

```
# BEGIN LETSENCRYPT AND COMODO
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteRule .* - [L]
# END LETSENCRYPT AND COMODO


<FilesMatch wp-login\.php>
  Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


#ADDED AS BACKUP PLAN, BUT DID NOT WORK EITHER
RewriteRule wp-login\.php$ - [END,R=403]




# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]

#If I comment this rule the wp-login.php file it's protected
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I've tried with R=404 or redirect to real file instead of R=403 but last rule always take on my redirect

to be clear:
I expect a forbidden page on:
https://example.com/wp-login.php
 and
https://example.com/subsite/wp-login.php

instead a 404 Wordpress page is returned in both case

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the solution:

```
RewriteRule wp-login\.php$ - [END,R=403]
```

don't work 'cause the previous rule already change the status, so we can use the status to prevent other rule to override our result:

```
RewriteCond "%{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}" "=403"
RewriteRule . - [L]
```

We can add a rule to catch the wp-login in multisite configuration
RewriteRule .*wp-login.php wp-login.php

The complete .htaccess now is:

```
# BEGIN LETSENCRYPT AND COMODO
#
# PREVENT SSL REDIRECT FOR CERTIFICATES PROCESS
#

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteRule .* - [L]
# END LETSENCRYPT AND COMODO

#BEGIN PROTECT WP-LOGIN 

#MULTISITE WP
#this rule it's only for multisite install
RewriteRule .*wp-login\.php wp-login.php  


#THIS RULES PREVENT SERVER LOAD ON A wp-login ATTACK
<FilesMatch wp-login\.php>
  Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

RewriteCond "%{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}" "=403"
RewriteRule . - [L]
#END PROTECT WP-LOGIN 




#FORCE SSL 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]




# BEGIN WordPress
#
# WORDPRESS MULTISITE WITH CUSTOM SUNRISE SETTING
#

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]

RewriteRule . index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```